# Debugging a NotificationEvent in Kernel Debug (Windows)

Tags: events, windbg, kernel32

I'm debugging a process which is like frozen:

- I suspect the root cause is the thread below `THREAD 877f4030  Cid 0568.0fb8` that is stuck on the user-mode call to `GetOverlappedResult`.

I have opened the dump with `kd.exe`.

Namely, I'm interested into knowing more about the `NotificationEvent` which obviously is never releasing our thread.

In the thread info we have:

```
879f6fdc  NotificationEvent
```

In what type should I cast address `879f6fdc` ? or in which structure field should I search for it, so as to understand, or have a clue to what is blocking the situation ?

As far as the Thread Infos goes, this thread currently does not list any IRP that would be in undesired or unfinished state.

---

Below entire Thread Information for the corresponding thread:

```
THREAD 877f4030  Cid 0568.0fb8  Teb: 7ff3d000 Win32Thread: 00000000 WAIT: (UserRequest) UserMode Non-Alertable
    879f6fdc  NotificationEvent
Not impersonating
DeviceMap                 89809fc8
Owning Process            87950030       Image:         OurProduct.exe
Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
Wait Start TickCount      1472232        Ticks: 5394 (0:00:01:24.146)
Context Switch Count      2791788        IdealProcessor: 0
UserTime                  00:00:06.848
KernelTime                00:00:09.890
Win32 Start Address MSVCR120!_threadstartex (0x721fbfb4)
Stack Init 8c761fd0 Current 8c761bc8 Base 8c762000 Limit 8c75f000 Call 0
Priority 8 BasePriority 8 UnusualBoost 0 ForegroundBoost 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
Kernel stack not resident.
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
8c761be0 824cfced 877f4030 00000000 8ab36120 nt!KiSwapContext+0x26 (FPO: [Uses EBP] [0,0,4])
8c761c18 824ceb4b 877f40f0 877f4030 879f6fdc nt!KiSwapThread+0x266
8c761c40 824c856f 877f4030 877f40f0 00000000 nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1df
8c761cb8 8267ae07 879f6fdc 00000006 826bca01 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x393
8c761d20 8248f8a6 00001018 00000000 00000000 nt!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc6
8c761d20 774f7094 00001018 00000000 00000000 nt!KiSystemServicePostCall (FPO: [0,3] TrapFrame @ 8c761d34)
09f9f61c 774f6a24 758b179c 00001018 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
09f9f620 758b179c 00001018 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
09f9f68c 758b7841 00001018 ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
09f9f6a0 758cb9e1 00001018 ffffffff 064f3d10 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
09f9f6b8 745be159 00001018 0639ee0c 09f9f6ec KERNELBASE!GetOverlappedResult+0x57 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

What is the correct way to proceed and know which event or synchronisation mechanism is faulting ?

---

some commands on the NotificationEvent address:

```
0: kd> !object 879f6fdc
879f6fdc: Not a valid object (ObjectType invalid)

0: kd> dt nt!_KEVENT 879f6fdc
   +0x000 Header           : _DISPATCHER_HEADER
```

and then:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_DISPATCHER_HEADER 879f6fdc
   +0x000 Type             : 0 ''
   +0x001 TimerControlFlags : 0 ''
   +0x001 Absolute         : 0y0
   +0x001 Coalescable      : 0y0
   +0x001 KeepShifting     : 0y0
   +0x001 EncodedTolerableDelay : 0y00000 (0)
   +0x001 Abandoned        : 0 ''
   +0x001 Signalling       : 0 ''
   +0x002 ThreadControlFlags : 0x4 ''
   +0x002 CpuThrottled     : 0y0
   +0x002 CycleProfiling   : 0y0
   +0x002 CounterProfiling : 0y1
   +0x002 Reserved         : 0y00000 (0)
   +0x002 Hand             : 0x4 ''
   +0x002 Size             : 0x4 ''
   +0x003 TimerMiscFlags   : 0 ''
   +0x003 Index            : 0y0
   +0x003 Processor        : 0y00000 (0)
   +0x003 Inserted         : 0y0
   +0x003 Expired          : 0y0
   +0x003 DebugActive      : 0 ''
   +0x003 ActiveDR7        : 0y0
   +0x003 Instrumented     : 0y0
   +0x003 Reserved2        : 0y0000
   +0x003 UmsScheduled     : 0y0
   +0x003 UmsPrimary       : 0y0
   +0x003 DpcActive        : 0 ''
   +0x000 Lock             : 0n262144
   +0x004 SignalState      : 0n0
   +0x008 WaitListHead     : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0x877f40f0 - 0x877f40f0 ]
```

from a former investigation I remember that if `+0x003 DpcActive` was 1, it would mean we'd be waiting for some hardware operation to put it to 0. But in this case it is 0.

So right now, I just don't know what this NotificationEvent is waiting for.
Any idea ?

Comment: Try getting a fuller user stack trace to see what's calling GetOverlappedResult(). Try `.process /p /r 87950030; .thread /p /r 877f4030; kb` Does that show more stack frames into the user stack?

Comment: I removed the additinal stackframes, calling from our product. We call  GetOverlappedResult after   calling `::CancelIo(port); ` and `::PurgeComm(port, PURGE_RXABORT|PURGE_RXCLEAR|PURGE_TXABORT|PURGE_TXCLEAR);` so as to wait and guarantee that operations have finished. The Msdn states that these two operations are not guaranteed to finished after being called.

Comment: Are you making sure `CancelIo()` returns TRUE before calling `GetOverlappedResult()`? If `CancelIo()` returns FALSE then no I/O was cancelled and therefore `GetOverlappedResult(..., bWait = TRUE)` *may* never return. I say *may* because the I/O may have completed just prior to your call to `CancelIo()`.

Comment: if it return FALSE, it only means there's been an error, isn't it ? However your advice seems really interesting. I'm going to dig in this way and check what are the returned value of CancelIo and PurgeIo in this case. Thx !

Comment: Take a look at this MS article and sample code. Even though they are calling `CancelIoEx()`, I believe it applies to `CancelIo()`. Look at how they check the return value of `CancelIoEx` and also check if `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` before calling `GetOverlappedResult()`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363789(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Events do not wait, Threads do. NotificationEvents are signaled by whoever would perform the operation and then notify the the waiters about the completion of the operation. In other words your stack is an example of a Async IO where we pass an overlapped structure with an hEvent set. reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx

You should be inspecting the source which has scheduled this IO or the type of IO we are waiting for instead of dumping out the event. The event will be signaled when the operation is completed.